# Mybatis insert fails with no exception

Tags: java, mysql, file, struts2, mybatis

I am trying to insert a file from a java application into a mysql table.

The call to the mapper completes without any exception, but at the end I don't find any records inside the table.

Maybe there is something wrong with the way I am mapping a file content to the blob field?

This is the bean:

```
public class CustomFile {
private int id;
private String title;
private String fileName;
private String fileType;
private String fileSize;
private byte[] fileContent;
private String fileExtension;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public String getFileType() {
    return fileType;
}

public void setFileType(String fileType) {
    this.fileType = fileType;
}

public String getFileSize() {
    return fileSize;
}

public void setFileSize(String fileSize) {
    this.fileSize = fileSize;
}

public byte[] getFileContent() {
    return fileContent;
}

public void setFileContent(byte[] fileContent) {
    this.fileContent = fileContent;
}

public String getFileExtension() {
    return fileExtension;
}

public void setFileExtension(String fileExtension) {
    this.fileExtension = fileExtension;
}

 }
```

And this is the mapping:

```
<insert id="saveFile" parameterType="CustomFile">

    INSERT INTO file SET
    Title = #{title},
    File_Name = #{fileName},
    File_Type = #{fileType},
    File_Size = #{fileSize},
    File_Content = #{fileContent,jdbcType=BLOB},
    File_Extension = #{fileExtension}

</insert>
```

this is the log4j log:

```
2012-02-04 20:14:20,656 DEBUG java.sql.Connection.debug:27 - ooo Connection Opened
2012-02-04 20:14:22,128 DEBUG java.sql.PreparedStatement.debug:27 - ==>  Executing: INSERT INTO file SET Title = ?, File_Name = ?, File_Type = ?, File_Size = ?, File_Content = ?, File_Extension = ? 
2012-02-04 20:14:22,135 DEBUG java.sql.PreparedStatement.debug:27 - ==> Parameters: Test(String), 294435318.jpg(String), image/jpeg(String), 10028(String), java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@13105f32(ByteArrayInputStream), image/jpeg(String)
2012-02-04 20:14:30,113 DEBUG java.sql.Connection.debug:27 - xxx Connection Closed
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you aren't using type File? I can't speak for the rest of the application but when using the struts2 file upload interceptor did you do it this way: struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html if so you should be able to dump some of the file content out, to the logger and verify that the struts2 side is good and drop it from the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you are failing to `commit` your insert?  May we see the code where you create the SqlSession?

Comment: that was it, I was more focused on a possible file content problem that I didn't consider I was not committing my transaction. Thanks!